# Capturing images using S40 5th edition FP1 Lite device in J2ME

Tags: java-me, nokia, midlet, series-40

I tried to test the source code for reading QR codes from http://qrdemo.com/qrmidlet.  Then, I tested it using the S40 5th edition FP1 Lite SDK.  It throws a javax.microedition.media.MediaException.  It tells that "capture://image" and "capture://video" are invalid locators.  Can anyone explain to me why are there devices like these?